# How do I handle date objects in ruby on rails forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select, date

I am using a rails helper that creates 3 select lists for the purpose of letting a user select a date.  If I assign the helper a name, it sets all 3 select lists to have that name, and then only the last one goes through (it overwrites the previous).  What I need to know is: What is the best way to take a set of 3 select lists (day, month, year), and combine them to create a date object and save it to my database?

Here is my date field:

```
<%= select_date Date.today, { :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 3 } %>
```

and here is the parameters passed to my controller (spat out from my dev log)

```
Parameters: {"date"=>{"month"=>"4", "day"=>"9", "year"=>"2009"}, 
"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"shows", 
"show"=>{"headline"=>"for example, \"Parking lot is next to the bookstore on Main Street\"", "venue_id"=>{"venue_id"=>""}, "cents"=>"00", "dollars"=>"00"}, 
"user_id"=>"3", "load_in"=>"-2", "show_time"=>"-2", "query"=>"Type venue name & location here...", "doors"=>"-2"}
```

As you can see, the date is passed.  Ideally, I would like the date passed as an acceptable date object to my controller.  Furthermore, I would like it passed in the "show" hash as it is show data.  Is this possible with some simple rails modifications? Or do I have to write some JS (...a bit dirty for this solution in my opinion)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want [`date_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001666) instead of [`select_date`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001670), since you want it associated with a particular field in your show object.

```
  date_select("show", "date", :default => Date.today, 
    :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => Date.today.year, 
    :end_year => Date.today.year + 3)
```